# multiTemplateDataRows, error There can only be one default row without a when predicate function

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I have added multiTemplateDataRows to my     `<mat-table multiTemplateDataRows>`

and have the following rows:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="data.displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: data.displayedColumns;"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['detail'];"></tr>
```

but i still receive the error "There can only be one default row without a when predicate function."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was on a later version of angular material where multiTemplateDataRows was not recognized.